# not render html to client with websockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

I use nodejs v0.10.12 and play around with websockets. On server side, I have a code like

```
//the http server
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end(clientHtml);
});
server.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8000');
})

//the websockets server
var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});

//connections, getting data from client , etc, etc

//try to send data to client
 connection.send('<b>Name</b></br>'+
result.row[i].p_name+
'</br></br><b>Description</b></br><textarea rows="20" cols="60">'
+result.rows[i].p_descr+
'</textarea>');
```

I want to send the data included in the `connection.send` from server to client through websockets.
The problem is that, on the client, the html tags also render, on the browser I get

```
<b>Name</b></br>testpoint5</br></br><b>Description</b></br><textarearows="20"cols="60">testpoint5</textarea>
```

I searched for "html tags through websockets" and such, but nothing usefull...

Any suggestions? How to make the html tags "work" on the client, instead of just rendering?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you later trying to insert that data into the DOM?

in that case you need to escape your tags. What I mean is `<` should become `&lt;` and `>` should become `&gt;`

There are other characters that you also need to escape. Look up 'escaping html entities' on google.

You should be doing this on the server-side:

```
connection.send("&lt;b&gt;Name&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/br&gt;"+result.rows[i].p_name+"&lt;/br&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;b&gt;Description&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/br&gt;&lt;textarearows="20"cols="60"&gt;"+result.rows[i].p_descr+"&lt;/textarea&gt;")
```

Comment: Later, I render the data in a `div`, on the client. Thanks for the tip, but it did not work, unfortunatelly. `&lt;` and `&gt;` still render on the browser

Comment: you should include the rendering code, because that is the issue here

Comment: sorry for the silly question, but by 'rendering code' you mean the front end or the back end code? or the code I get on the browser?

Comment: the frontend code that inserts that stuff from the websocket into your page (and that doesnt work correctly)

Comment: I just fix it. At the front end, at the `onmessage` function I had `response.textContent = received_msg;` to render the data, with "response" being a simple div. I should have `document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=received_msg;`. Works just fine now, without having to escape html entities. This is **so** embarrassing, creating a "problem" out of my own negligence. Anyhow, mkoryak, thank you for your time.